# ReactJS + React Router: How to center div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router

I currently have a ReactJS + React Router project set up and in Chrome dev tool under elements shows:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div data-reactroot>
      <div>
        <div class="container">Center Me</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

with styling and none for `class="wrapper"`:

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Yet the `<div class="container">Center Me</div>` is staying at the top and centered horizontally but not vertically.

I checked the size of that div and it is extremely short but takes up full width of the browser page.

What could I be doing wrong? How can I center `<div class="container">Center Me</div>`? I even tried to set `100% for width and height` on a higher level, but still does not work.

Comment: The element that you align inside should be a tag such as a <div>. You'll need styling on Html, Body to tell that you want the min height and min width to be 100vh (view-height) and 100vw (view-width).

Comment: Every parent of `.container` needs `height: 100%;` too

Comment: @Win so where exactly in the tree should I add the height and width?

Comment: @MichaelCoker Added to every parent yet still the same...

Comment: Make sure you include:- html, body { min-height: 100vh; min-width: 100vw; }

Comment: @Win I added html, body { min-height: 100vh; min-width: 100vw; } yet it is still the same. Is it just html and body that I need to add to?

Comment: Ahh shame I don't have my laptop. You need to add the height and width to all divs that exist above container and you need to put the wrap a div around the centre me text.

Comment: @Win Do you mind showing in codepen etc. with the same set up?

Comment: @Win and why is it that 100% wouldn't work?

Comment: check this ref
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125775/reactjs-react-router-how-to-center-div/50796306#50796306

Answer (score 79):

Just:

```
<div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', height: '100vh'}}>
    <h1> I am centered </h1>
</div>
```

or css:

```css
.centered {
  height: 100vh; /* Magic here */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered">
  <h1> I am centered </h1>
</div>
```

## Updates:

To center a div within the body, you can:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <h1>Centered!</h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a code example that basically recreates your page but without react. Hope this helps and shoot away if you have any questions.

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div data-reactroot>
      <div class="container">
        <div>
          <!-- Anything below this line will be centered -->
          <div>Hello World!</div>
          <div>Center Me</div>
          <!-- Anything above this line will be centered -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Before I accept the answer and upvote, say if I have another `<div>` or `<p>`, how can I add it to the next line and have it centered as well? I just added it after `<div>Center Me</div>` and it is in the same line.

Answer (score 3):

I just wrap my `div` with `Grid` and added `justify="center" attr.`:

```
<Grid container spacing={2} justify="center"></Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for react,

for becomes htmlFor, and class becomes className etc.

see full list of how HTML attributes are changed here:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: I'm aware but in Chrome dev tool under elements, it just shows as class and besides the wrapper does not have any styling.

Answer (score 1):

```
const App = () => {
  const styles = {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: '100vh',
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles}>
      <h2>Hello All</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, you need to use className not class.

```
className="wrapper"
```

Comment: I'm aware but in Chrome dev tool under elements, it just shows as class and besides the wrapper does not have any styling.